# Restrict access for registration page in magento

Tags: php, magento, ip, registration

I want certain IP Addresses to be blocked or not given access to my Registration page ( signup page ) for my magento store.. can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to redirect using htaccess

`# permanently redirect specific IP request for single page
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 123\.456\.789
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /requested-page\.html$
RewriteRule .* /just-for-you.html [R=301,L]`

source: http://perishablepress.com/permanently-redirect-a-specific-ip-request-for-a-single-page-via-htaccess/

Comment: No bro.. i don't wanna redirect them to any other page.. i want the person to know the reason why its blocked for them.. so i need a popup like message to come when they click on SIGN UP.. Is this possible? awaiting reply !!